# Extract data from PDF file with Python

Tags: python, pdf

I want to use Python to extract data from my tax return PDF document. I am using the `PyPDF2` library to read the file, and that works fine.

```
import PyPDF2 as p2

pdf_file = open("my2017TaxReturn.pdf", "rb")
pdf_read = p2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)

page = pdf_read.getPage(18)
data = page.extractText()
print(data)
```

However, this is the output that I get:

`Cost of goods sold (attach Form 1125-A)   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Gross profit. Subtract line 2 from line 1c     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Net gain (loss) from Form 4797, line 17    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Other income (loss)  Add lines 3 through 5Compensation of officers (see instrs. - attach Form 1125-E)   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Salaries and wages (less employment credits)   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Repairs and maintenance   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Bad debts  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Rents  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Taxes and licenses   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Depreciation not claimed on Form 1125-A or elsewhere on return    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~DepletionAdvertising    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Pension, profit-sharing, etc., plans   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Employee benefit programs   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Other deductions Add lines 7 through 19   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Subtract line 20 from line 6Excess net passive income or LIFO recapture tax~~~~~~Tax from Schedule D  (Form 1120S)    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Add lines 22a and 22b2017 estimated tax payments and 2016 overpayment credited to 2017    ~~~~Tax deposited with Form 7004  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Credit for federal tax paid on fuels    ~~~~~~~~~~~Add lines 23a through 23cEstimated tax penalty (see instructions). Check if Form 2220 is attached    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ If line 23d is smaller than the total of lines 22c and 24, enter amount owed  ~~~~~~~~~~~~ If line 23d is larger than the total of lines 22c and 24, enter amount overpaidEnter amount from line 26 Signature of officerDateTitlePTINDateJWAForm  (2017)~~|||SignHere1120SU.S.`

The numbers that I want to read seem encrypted with ~~~~~~.

**Is there any way to get around this to read the actual number on my tax return form?**

Thanks!

Comment: ocr may be the only way

Comment: Does the PDF have layers in it? Alternatively, is it a form where you can enter numbers manually, or was it automatically generated by a tax preparer program like Turbo Tax?

Comment: You could try `pdfminer`, sometimes it gives different results